# How to use admob using capacitor in Ionic?

Tags: android, ionic-framework, admob, ionic4, capacitor

I have problems with admob-free plugin. I executed these command in a ionic 4 project:

```
    ionic start myapp sidemenu
    ionic capacitor add android 
    ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-admob-free  --save --variable ADMOB_APP_ID="myadmobid"
    npm install @ionic-native/admob-free
    Ionic capacitor sync android 
    ionic capacitor run android
```

when I test the program on my device android studio shows the next error and the app stop.

```
 FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.danieltrevino.myapp, PID: 29617
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/android/gms/internal/zzur;
        at com.google.android.gms.ads.BaseAdView.<init>(Unknown Source:3)
        at com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView.<init>(Unknown Source:1)
        at name.ratson.cordova.admob.banner.BannerExecutor$1.run(BannerExecutor.java:70)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:280)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6706)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzur
        at java.lang.VMClassLoader.findLoadedClass(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.findLoadedClass(ClassLoader.java:738)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:363)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312
```

I read that the problem could be about google play services versions

android/build.gradle

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

android/capacitor-cordova-android-plugins/build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.2'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
    flatDir{
        dirs 'src/main/libs', 'libs'
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'src/main/libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'org.apache.cordova:framework:7.0.0'
    // SUB-PROJECT DEPENDENCIES START
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:11.0.4"
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:11.0.4"
    // SUB-PROJECT DEPENDENCIES END
}

// PLUGIN GRADLE EXTENSIONS START
apply from: "cordova.variables.gradle"
// PLUGIN GRADLE EXTENSIONS END

for (def func : cdvPluginPostBuildExtras) {
    func()
}
```

I am following the next [tutorial](https://www.freakyjolly.com/ionic-4-implement-admob-free-native-plugin-in-latest-ionic-4-applications-more-efficiently/) , do you know some solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

The admob plugin has some issues due to the new ionic 4/5 version of the framework. For the ones using capacitor, there's two plugins( community plugins) that are avalaible now, they're pretty new so you might find some bugs there.

Those two plugins (at the moment of writing this, so you can find more than two) are found in the docs [capacitor's documentation](https://capacitor.ionicframework.com/docs/community/plugins/)

The two plugins right now are:

[plugin 1](https://github.com/rahadur/capacitor-admob)
[plugin 2](https://github.com/rdlabo/capacitor-admob)